# How to get the long output of a mysql command in a file?

Tags: mysql, shell

I would like to have  the result of  :

```
 mysql -u root -p wordpressdb < script3.sql
```

in a file but  :

```
 mysql -u root -p wordpressdb < script3.sql > result.txt
```

is not working

Thanks and regards

Comment: Try adding ` 2>&1`  to your command. That redirects stderr as well

Comment: @exussum your solution work thanks